# Using AS value in later on in query

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following example query:

```
SELECT foo.bar,
DATEDIFF(
    # Some more advanced logic, such as IF(,,), which shouldn't be copy pasted
) as bazValue
FROM foo
WHERE bazValue >= CURDATE() # <-- This doesn't work
```

How can I make the `bazValue` available later on in the query? I'd prefer this, since I believe that it's enough to maintain the code in one place if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways around this problem that you can use in MySQL:

By using an inline view (this should work in most other versions of SQL, too):

```
select * from
(SELECT foo.bar,
 DATEDIFF(
     # Some more advanced logic, such as IF(,,), which shouldn't be copy pasted
 ) as bazValue
 FROM foo) buz
WHERE bazValue >= CURDATE()
```

By using a HAVING clause (using column aliases in HAVING clauses is specific to MySQL):

```
SELECT foo.bar,
DATEDIFF(
    # Some more advanced logic, such as IF(,,), which shouldn't be copy pasted
) as bazValue
FROM foo
HAVING bazValue >= CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [Problems with Column Aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/problems-with-alias.html):

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a `WHERE` clause. This restriction is imposed because when the `WHERE` clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined. For example, the following query is illegal:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_name
>  WHERE cnt > 0 GROUP BY id;
> ```
>
> The `WHERE` clause determines which rows should be included in the `GROUP BY` clause, but it refers to the alias of a column value that is not known until after the rows have been selected, and grouped by the `GROUP BY`.

You can however reuse the aliased expression, and if it uses deterministic functions the query optimiser will ensure that cached results are reused:

```sql
SELECT foo.bar,
       DATEDIFF(
         -- your arguments
       ) as bazValue
FROM   foo
WHERE  DATEDIFF(
         -- your arguments
       ) >= CURDATE()
```

Alternatively, you can move the filter into a `HAVING` clause (where aliased columns will already have been calculated and are therefore available) - but performance will suffer as indexes cannot be used and the filter will not be applied until after results have been compiled.

Comment: Thanks for the quote! I'm aware that I can copy-paste the entire logic, but I'm trying to avoid that..

Answer (score 1):

As MySQL doesn't support CTE, consider using `inline view`:

```
SELECT foo.bar,
FROM foo, 
(SELECT DATEDIFF(
    # Some more advanced logic, such as IF(,,), which shouldn't be copy pasted
    ) as bazValue
) AS iv
WHERE iv.bazValue >= CURDATE()
```